# Parse Crash Reporting import with pods not working on Swift

Tags: swift, crash, parse-platform, reporting

I have update the Parse SDK to 1.6.0 through CocoaPods. 
IT works seems I am able to use the Local Datastore. However when I try to enable ParseCrashReporting doing 
    ParseCrashReporting.enable()

But Xcode does not find ParseCrashReporting.

Anyone having the same issue ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 12):

ParseCrashReporting is in its own cocoapod spec. Make sure you add `pod 'ParseCrashReporting'` to your `Podfile`. Then import the headers as @Lucas pointed out.

Reference: http://cocoapods.org/?q=parsecrashreporting

Comment: Do I still have to do the _Upload Symbol Files_ step manually even if I add this via CocoaPods?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and you should [download the new Parse sdk](https://www.parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/latest), that comes with the following frameworks:

- Bolts.framework
- Parse.framework
- **ParseCrashReporting.framework**
- ParseFacebookUtils.framework
- ParseUI.framework

In order to work, you should add the SQLite 3.framework and libstdc++.6.dylib to your project too
Don't forget to add on your Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import <ParseCrashReporting/ParseCrashReporting.h>
```

Comment: Nope. Parse doesn't distribute ParseCrashReporting. They're awful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll also point out that as @cojoj mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910446/4139760), you should include `use_frameworks!` at the top of your Podfile to take advantage of umbrella headers. This [blogpost](http://iosdevbits.blogspot.com/2014/12/finally-cocoapods-with-swift.html) lays it out clearly. It worked for me in getting the Parse SDK set up with CocoaPods and Swift.