# Old libraries, new CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Because **CocoaPods 0.36** are availbable to anyone and they are now coming with Swift and Frameworks support I have one question that is bothering me today...

I create `Podfile` in my project directory, fill it with:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

And run `pod install` as usual... You know this story. But when I open my `.xcworkspace` and go to any ViewController and `import SwiftyJSON` it just works but when I try to do the same thing with AFNetworking I get `No such module 'AFNetworking'`. Of course, I can create a **Bridging-Header** and import it with the Objective-C way but when I read [this](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/) blog post I can see:

> To use this subspec in Swift, without a generated umbrella header, you
>   would need to create a bridging header and use an import like `#import
>   <AFNetworking/AFNetworking+UIKit.h`. With the generated umbrella
>   header, you just need to `import AFNetworking`, if you have the subspec
>   included in your Podfile.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I suppose that manual Bridging-Header is no longer needed if we add libraries with CocoaPods, right? So, why this isn't working?

Answer (score 14):

As I thought... This example which I provided in OP is incorrect... Well, basically it's correct because it's working like it should. Let me show you a counter example.

I have a Swift project but I want to use only Objective-C pods (AFNetworking, SSPullToRefresh etc.). Now we have some troubles because when you provide those Objective-C pods in `Podfile` they'll be added to Pods target as a **static libraries**. You probably now that CocoaPods are now switching to **Frameworks** (If you want to know the difference please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245761/difference-between-framework-and-static-library-in-xcode4-and-how-to-call-them) question). Back to topic... There are two possible solutions to this conflict sitation:

1. You manually create `YourProject-Bridging-Header.h` and `#import` those libraries... This is the old way used even before Swift integration.
2. You include this magic `use_frameworks!` method call inside your `Podfile`. By doing this you force CocoaPods to create frameworks instead of static libraries.

Now, let me explain why you'd prefer the second solution... As OP states, CocoaPods now automatically create **Umbrella Headers** ([learn about them](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/)). It's the convenient way for you to skip manual creation of bridging header.

I've found a solution [here](http://iosdevbits.blogspot.com/2014/12/finally-cocoapods-with-swift.html) so without this post I would probably still be struggling with this problem. Cheers to the author!

Comment: From your reading of that document, did you see a means of using the cocoapods auto generated umbrella file as your preferred means for use in *Obj-c* projects?  Ie. configure cocoapods to generate the bridging header as `AFNetworking.h` instead of `Pods-iOS Example-AFNetworking-umbrella.h`, so that it would always track the set of public headers - a "single point of truth"?  From my reading it is only intended for visibility by Swift code.

Comment: The umbrella header is precisely created for Swift. So, there is no need to use it with Objective-C projects... Why would you? I was only struggling with mixed projects where the main language I write is Swift and some of Pods can be Objective-C libraries.

Comment: The umbrella file is a concept that relates to frameworks, and fameworks are / were new to Obj-c as well.  The umbrella file is just the grand summary of all public headers in the framework, and is the `MyFramework.h` in `#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>`.  Under the hood, cocoapods generates a new and uniquely named umbrella file and registers it in the modulemap to make it available via `@import MyFramework`.  The naming and convention of this is the subject of debate in https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3092.  It is how both Swfit and Obj-c code find Obj-c symbols.